# flex tree node types

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, tree, itemrenderer

i have a tree of nodes that i dont want some type of nodes to appear in the tree, i can check the data on tree item renderer for each specific node type, so i have one type that i dont want it to be shown as tree node, like it doesn't exist.

```
if(this.data.type == TypeEnum.id){
            this.visible=false;
            this.height = 0;
        }
        else {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
public function init(e:Event):void{
   if(this.data.bad==true){
      this.visible=false;
      this.height=0;
      this.width=0;
   }
}
```

or just add some `filter` function like [here](http://www.davidarno.org/2009/04/01/how-to-filter-all-nodes-of-a-flex-tree-component/)

Comment: didn't work, first option stalls the program with white screen, even its exactly what i need, and the second one works with xml data, could i use it with objects?

Comment: Hi again, it worked after i removed the width statement, but in a strange way, the nodes disappeared,but some height still exists... i need the discloser icon for other nodes that are not this type i want to disappear... but when opening the nodes.... any node that disappears keeps some empty height.

Comment: i mean this function inside of itemRenderer component. and second link will work fine with any type of data, just modify it.

Comment: and show me your code, you could use something like pastebin.com

Comment: ok, thanks for the help, i will modify the example to work for me... but i was wounding why the node disappeared but the height which is zero still affects the tree, i used this code in the update display function...  and its much easer to use inside the item renderer

Comment: try to call something like `container.invalidatedisplaylist` after removing current data from itemRenderer from dataProvider. or make a height to zero and try to apply dynamic height in settings of container.